# Enter Checkbox values using JQuery code

Tags: jquery, html

I use this JQUERY code to ender data to a HTML table.First time show checkbox values .Next time not showing the valuees that get first time.This is the JQUERY code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#details').on('click', '.remove', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    })

    $('#submit').on('click',function(){
        var st = '';
        $('#trtform input[type=text],select,input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
            st = st+ '<td width="150" align="center">'+$(this).val()+'</td>';
            $(this).val('');
        });
        var remove = $('<td />', {text : 'X', 'class': 'remove'});
        $('#details').append( $('<tr />').append(st, remove) );
    });
});
```

Follow this link to get better understand

http://jsfiddle.net/S4FT7/63/

Comment: added an answer, have a look on it.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are clearing it's value

You are saying

```
$(this).val('');
```

This will clear the value of `checkbox` also. You should say

```
if($(this).is(':checkbox'))
    $(this).prop('checked',false); 
else
    $(this).val('');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/S4FT7/66/)